# Sending long sms with sendMultipartTextMessage

Tags: android, sms

I use this code:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, null, null);
```

Apparently no error occurs while executing this code but sms is not received.
This code works successfully when sending short (<=160 chars) sms.

What can the cause be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts =sm.divideMessage(LONG_TEXT);
int numParts = parts.size();

ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
     sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0,  mSendIntent, 0));
     deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, mDeliveryIntent, 0));
}

sm.sendMultiPartTextMessage(mDestAddr,null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents)
```

***Try on real device.

Comment: Even with my own code, sometimes long sms is received (i think specially the first time). maybe some criteria or spam prevention mechanism is in effect from the provider.

Comment: yes it seems that the carrier filters messages based on some criteria (like many repetitive characters). seems I can avoid that by sending meaningful looking messages.

Answer (score 0):

Even with my own code, sometimes long sms is received (i think specially the first time). maybe some criteria or spam prevention mechanism is in effect from the cellular company.

Later:

yes it seems that the carrier filters messages based on some criteria (like many repetitive characters). seems I can avoid that by sending meaningful looking messages.